# navigation drawer не работают пункты меню

Tags: android

при компиляции ошибок не выдает. Возможно проблемы связанны с support.v4...

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.user.salon;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.user.salon.MenuFragments.AboutFragment;
import com.example.user.salon.MenuFragments.GalleryFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private SharedPreferences pref;

    //drowable menu fragments
    AboutFragment aboutFragment;
    GalleryFragment galleryFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pref = getPreferences(0);
        initFragment();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        aboutFragment = new AboutFragment();
        galleryFragment = new GalleryFragment();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);  //was changed to add
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }

    private void initFragment(){
        Fragment fragment;
        if(pref.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false)){
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        }else {
            fragment = new LoginFragment();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }




    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, aboutFragment);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, galleryFragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

**avtivity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="About" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />

    </group>

</menu>
```

**AboutFragment**

```
package com.example.user.salon.MenuFragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.user.salon.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link AboutFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link AboutFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public AboutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment AboutFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static AboutFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        AboutFragment fragment = new AboutFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

//    @Override
//    public void onAttach(Context context) {
//        super.onAttach(context);
//        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
//            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
//        } else {
//            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
//                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
//        }
//    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Должно помочь: https://youtu.be/Y-YcoNNagh8 Там всё понятно объясняется.

Comment: я по этому видео и делал)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте с помощью Handler.
Вот так делаю я

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.menu_profile) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Fragment fragment=new Profile();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,fragment).commit();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```